# How to create a dictionary from a list of lists in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Given a list of lists, how can I create a dictionary where the keys are all the items in the list (one copy), and the values are the number of times they are the first item in the list?

Given:

```
[['banana', 'oranges', 'grapes'],['banana', 'grapes'],['grapes', 'oranges', 'banana']]
```

Expected:

```
{'banana': 2, 'grapes': 1, 'oranges': 0}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Comment: Please mark the most helpful answer as accepted, if your question is answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First get the list of first elements:

```
filtered_list = [x[0] for x in initial_list]
```

And here are your unique elements:

```
unique_elements = set([y for x in initial_list for y in x])
```

Now initialize a dictionary with keys from unique elements and values of zero:

```
counts = {e: 0 for e in unique_elements}
```

Finally update the values of the dictionary with the frequencies of each element in the filtered list. Since you asked a solution without `counter`, here is a simple loop to achieve that:

```
for i in filtered_list:
    counts[i] = counts.get(i, 0) + 1

print(counts)
# {'banana': 2, 'grapes': 1, 'oranges': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets to get unique names present in the sub lists:

```
initial_list = [['banana', 'oranges', 'grapes'],['banana', 'grapes'],['grapes', 'oranges', 'banana']]

unique = set()

for l in initial_list:
    unique = unique.union(set(l))
```

Then counting in how many list each item is present (assuming each item is either present or not, not duplicated):

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for element in unique:
    for l in initial_list:
        result[element] += (element == l[0])
```

Defaultict is used to get an initial value of 0
And you should have your result in `result`

The fact that`bool` are a subclass of `int` is used to evaluate `element == l[0]` either to `1` or `0`

Without `collections` you would need to edit the last line to be:

```
try:
    result[element] += (element == l[0])
except KeyError:
    result[element] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create list of lists:

```
ll = [['banana', 'oranges', 'grapes'], ['banana', 'grapes'], ['grapes', 'oranges', 'banana']]
```

Get unique keys:

```
from itertools import chain

d = dict.fromkeys(chain(*ll), 0)
```

Count first elements of lists:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

c = Counter(map(itemgetter(0), ll))
```

Update and show result:

```
d.update(dict(c))
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'banana': 2, 'oranges': 0, 'grapes': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the previous responses failed for me. This is a very fast implementation that works:

```
# l is a list of lists
import itertools
ext_l = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))
l_dic = {element:0 for element in set(ext_l)}
for i in ext_l: l_dic[i] += 1
print(l)
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple implementation

```
l = [['banana', 'oranges', 'grapes'],['banana', 'grapes'],['grapes', 'oranges', 'banana']]
unique_items = set([i for sl in l for i in sl])
d = dict()
for item in unique_items:
    d[item] = 0

for sublist in l:
    d[sublist[0]] += 1

print(d)
# output
# {'grapes': 1, 'oranges': 0, 'banana': 2}
```

To maintain order

```
d = dict()
for sl in l:
    d[sl[0]] = d.get(sl[0],0) + 1
print(d)
# {'banana': 2, 'grapes': 1}

unique_items = set([i for sl in l for i in sl])
for item in unique_items:
    if item not in d:
        d[item] = 0
print(d)
# {'banana': 2, 'grapes': 1, 'oranges': 0}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without collections or counter. Just a simple for loop maybe?

Comment: is it possible to change the order? Like banana first, then grapes, then oranges.

Comment: @PotionSeller Insertion order is maintained, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared). You need to change the insertion order.